# AT commands hang up

Tags: c#, .net, at-command

I have the following snippet code which I am using to simulate a call on a PC as a dialer using AT Commands.

The problem I have is that sometimes, for a random number which is dialled, even though the user clicks the "hang up" button on the windows form, the call still continues dialing in the background.

The actual dial call is this code:

```
SerialPort po = new SerialPort();
po.PortName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("modemPort");
po.BaudRate = int.Parse("9600");
po.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
po.Parity = Parity.None;
po.StopBits = StopBits.One;
po.ReadTimeout = int.Parse("300");
po.WriteTimeout = int.Parse("300");
po.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
po.Open();
po.WriteLine("ATD" + phoneNumber + ";\r");
```

Then when clicking the Hang Up button, I have this code:

```
po.DiscardInBuffer();
po.DiscardOutBuffer();
po.Close();
```

This sometimes keeps the call dialing in the background.

I even added the following to test it out, but still the same result.

```
po.WriteLine("ATH" + "\r");
po.WriteLine("ATH0;\r");
po.WriteLine("ATH+CHUP;\r");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the AT command set is officially called the [Hayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) command set. The information on the Wiki page offer help. Various reasons can cause the hangup (ATH0) not to work. First of all I'm not sure about the use of the semicolon, it should not be needed. Secondly, the modem may be in data mode so you need to switch it to manned mode first (using '+++') before writing the hangup command. Another options is to configure the modem to drop the connection on drop of the DTR signal (and then drop the DTR to hangup). More info on this [here](https://docs.kde.org/trunk4/en/kdenetwork/kppp/modem-hangup.html).